# Swift split string to get file type from URL

Tags: swift, string, cocoa, interface-builder

I am using NSOpenPanel to import a file, and as such I am able to get the complete URL path, and can get this in string format, but I am wondering how I can go about getting the type of the file from the URL? An example of what I am trying to do is as follows:

How would I split this URL (stored as string): *Desktop/exampleFiles/targetFile.png*

and get back from it the type, which in this case is: *.png*

Comment: Please look at the reference documentation for `URL`. There's a pretty obvious property to get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`pathExtension`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780487-pathextension) property after contructing a `URL` from your initial string:

```
let string = "Desktop/exampleFiles/targetFile.png"

let url: URL? = URL(string: string)
let urlExtension: String? = url?.pathExtension
```

Comment: Wow, this was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 and safely unwrapping optional string

```
let url = "http://www.yourUrl.com/yourImage.png"
guard let urlString = URL(string: url) else { return }
let urlExtension = urlString.pathExtension
print(urlExtension)
```